# How can I convert an AES Key to a UInt and back?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm trying to make a hybrid encryption scheme, using RSA and AES, so I need to encrypt my AES key. I'm using the AES key from the `System.Security.Cryptography` AES class. I'm getting the AES Key using `myAES.Key`. I know that I can easily do this with the RSA class from the same namespace, however I'm trying to learn how all of this stuff works, not use it for something that needs high security.
Right now, all I need to do is convert the AES key to a UInt and back (for decryption), so that is satisfies the requirements of 1 < aeskey < n.
If you didn't already know, the AES Key is just a `byte[]`.

I tried the following code:

```
using(Aes aes = Aes.Create())
{
   string originalKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(aes.Key);
   Console.WriteLine("Original: " + originalKey);
   uint number = BitConverter.ToUInt32(aes.Key);
   Console.WriteLine("New Number: " + Convert.ToString(number));
   byte[] roundTripArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
   string roundTripString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(roundTripArray);
   Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: " + roundTripString);
   Console.WriteLine("Successful: " + Convert.ToString(roundTripString == originalKey));
}
```

I got this output:

Original: �Vg9;x�(�K�q�#tUD�u.I�b
���

New Number: 963073790

Round Trip: �Vg9

Successful: False

The round trip is somehow losing the rest of the data, it has a section of the original but for some reason is losing the rest in the process.

Comment: An AES key is at least 128 bit, how should such a key fit into a [`uint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint32?view=net-7.0) (32 bit)? For a conversion into an integer rather a [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-biginteger-ctor(system-readonlyspan((system-byte))-system-boolean-system-boolean)) is needed. By the way, a key (which is usually a random byte sequence) cannot be UTF-8 decoded without corrupting the data.

Comment: I'll use a BigInteger instead, thanks!

Comment: Another recommendation is never print binary data as String (and try to use it for a comparison). Binary data should be encoded e.g. to hex before printing, especially if you are trying to compare it with a different value.